# How to get a user input and print it in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm new to programming, was playing around with C# application...
What is wrong with my code?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String text = textBox1.Text;
    text = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(text);
    MessageBox.Show("hi"+ text);
}
```

I'm just trying to get user input and print it in c# application.

Comment: You are using windows forms and trying to get input from the console (like a console app) .. Decide which route you want to take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is are you using a Console application or a User Interface application (such as WPF, WinForms)?

If you are using a Console application then you should:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine(); //Getting an input from the user.
Console.WriteLine(input); //Print the input.
```

If you are using a User Interface application such as WPF then you should:

```
string input = textBox1.Text; //You should have a textbox in the view with the name textBox1
MessageBox.Show("hi" + input); //Shows a message box.
```